# When should you repeat the same subject in a compound sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, writing-style, conjunction-reduction, compound-sentences, compound-subjects

I'd like to know when it is required to repeat the pronoun after a clause or an interjection within the same phrase.
For example, which of these two phrases would be considered correct:

1. I've recently sold my first book, a period drama which I've written years ago, **and I have** another book optioned.
2. I've recently sold my first book, a period drama which I've written years ago, **and have** another book optioned.

Notice the second version doesn’t say *I* again. Is that still grammatically correct?

Comment: I'm guessing the other choice is supposed to be: "I've recently sold my first book, a period drama written years ago, and..."

Comment: @GEdgar No, there’s a hard to see duplicated *I*.

Comment: Why, since you used "I've" at the start of the sentence, does your first example use "I have" later on?  "I've" in the second usage would be far more idiomatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second option seems better. I would also like to suggest a change. " I've recently sold my first book, a period drama which I wrote years ago, and have another book optioned. 
To address your first concern, you can use an additional 'I' , it's not grammatically incorrect. It's just that in English we try to minimise the repetition of the same word in a sentence as much as we can.

Comment: Yes but she asked when it is required, not when it seems better.

Comment: She has specifically asked , " which of these two phrases would be considered correct ?"

Comment: And you have not answered that question. "Seems better" makes no statement about grammaticality of one versus the other. Are you suggesting that the first version is grammatically incorrect?

Comment: I've addressed your concern.

Comment: Well done, thanks.

Comment: thanks for the prompt and clear answer and also for your suggestion.

Comment: I had just submitted a comment under the question that I would write *which I wrote*, when I saw this answer. (I've since removed my comment since you address it here.)

Comment: Yes, a change of tense seemed necessary.